# Formatting issues when removing row numbers in datatable

Tags: r, datatable

I am using the R package `DT` to create a table. This table contains hyperlinks and the issue that I am having is that when I put `rownames = FALSE` to remove the row numbers, the formatting on the hyperlinks goes away. I was wondering if anyone had a solution to this problem?

Example data:

```
structure(list(school = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Linfield", 
"OSU", "UO", "Willamette"), class = "factor"), mascot = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("bearcats", "beavers", "ducks", "wildcats"
), class = "factor"), website = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("<a href=\"http://oregonstate.edu/\">oregonstate.edu</a>", 
"<a href=\"https://www.linfield.edu/\">linfield.edu</a>", "<a href=\"https://www.uoregon.edu/\">uoregon.edu</a>", 
"<a href=\"https://www.willamette.edu/\">willamette.edu</a>"), class = "factor"), 
    School_colors = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("<span style=\"color:green\">green & yellow</span>", 
    "<span style=\"color:orange\">orange & black</span>", "<span style=\"color:purple\">purple and red</span>", 
    "<span style=\"color:red\">red and yellow</span>"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Code used to generate table WITH row names

```
datatable(df,escape = c(1,2,3))
```

[image: example1]

Code used to generate table WITHOUT row names

```
datatable(df, rownames = FALSE,escape = c(1,2,3))
```

[image: example2]

As you can see, with the second example code, the formatting in the third column is no longer there. What I want to do is create a table without row numbers but also keep the formatting of the hyperlinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your deleted the rownames the indexes of your columns changed as well.
Therefore you should change your escape argument to only 1 and 2.

```
datatable(df, rownames = FALSE,escape = c(1,2))
```

A simple escape = FALSE also works for you.

```
datatable(df, rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE)
```

Comment: That works like a charm. Thank you for the help